# Ant Task to FTP only specified files

Tags: ant, ftp

I have an Ant task that FTPs all files in a specified directory, and it uses a fileset:

```
<fileset dir="${publicDirectory}">
  <include name="media/**/*" />
</fileset>
```

I have a file that contains all the files that I would like to include:

```
media/some/dir/1.txt
media/some/other/2.txt
...
```

How can I have the fileset read the file and only include whatever I've listed there?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried quite a few things, but nothing seems to be able to get around a basic issue: The `<ftp>` task works only on filesets and not other types of resources. I've tried various filterchains, but to no avail.

The best I could come up with was using the [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) `<for>` or `<foreach>` task to loop through the file and then use an `<exec>` task to execute the command line version of *ftp*.